# How to get a dynamic text in span element in Java Selenium?

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I am searching on a site by selecting a date filter over the filter. I'm trying to get the total number of records shown in the filter result.

There is a phrase "Showing 1 to 50 of 130" under the records shown on the site, and I want to dynamically take this phrase and display it on the console.

I tried many things but none of them were successful.

When I take it with InnerHTML it shows the data but all records before filtering. The value of the field changes as I filter, and I want the changed value to be retrieved when I filter.

I tried to get this data with xpath and CSS selector but it didn't work.

**I am sharing the final version of my code below.**

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'pagination-summary')]/xpath[1]")));
```

**That's the error message i got:**

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(@class, 'pagination-summary')]/xpath[1]"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
By locator = By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'pagination-summary')]");

WebElement element = driver.findElement(locator);

String text = element.getText();

System.out.println(text);
```

In one single line

```
System.out.println(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'pagination-summary')]")).getText());
```